# SciPy lfilter with initial conditions applied along any axis of N-D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering

According to SciPy docs for [lfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html):

zi : array_like, optional
Initial conditions for the filter delays. It is a vector (or array of vectors for an N-dimensional input) of length `max(len(a),len(b))-1`. If zi is None or is not given then initial rest is assumed. See lfiltic for more information.

The following code calls lfilter, and passes zi using [lfilter_zi](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter_zi.html#scipy.signal.lfilter_zi) such that the length of the last dimension of zi is `max(len(a),len(b))-1`. However it raises an error, depending on the axis of application:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig

def apply_filter(B, A, signal, axis=-1):
   # apply filter, setting proper initial state (doesn't assume rest)
   filtered, zf = sig.lfilter(B, A, signal, 
             zi=sig.lfilter_zi(B, A) * np.take(signal, 0, axis=axis)[..., np.newaxis], axis=axis)
   return filtered

B, A = sig.butter(1, 0.5)
x = np.random.randn(12, 50)
apply_filter(B, A, x, axis=1)    # works without error
apply_filter(B, A, x, axis=0)    # raises ValueError
```

`ValueError: The number of initial conditions must be max([len(a),len(b)]) - 1`

How can I avoid the error, and apply a filter along any axis without assuming initial rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial conditions in `zi` must be in the same axis as the axis given to `lfilter`.  Change this:

```
np.take(signal, 0, axis=axis)[..., np.newaxis]
```

to

```
np.take(signal, [0], axis=axis)
```

---

The difference between `np.take(signal, 0, axis=axis)` and `np.take(signal, [0], axis=axis)` is that the latter preserves the number of dimensions.  E.g.

```
In [105]: signal
Out[105]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

In [106]: signal.shape
Out[106]: (3, 5)
```

If we `take` the first index from axis 1, we get a 1-d array with shape (3,):

```
In [107]: a = np.take(signal, 0, axis=1)

In [108]: a.shape
Out[108]: (3,)

In [109]: a
Out[109]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

If, instead, we use the list `[0]` in the `indices` argument, we get an array with shape (3, 1):

```
In [110]: b = np.take(signal, [0], axis=1)

In [111]: b.shape
Out[111]: (3, 1)

In [112]: b
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0],
       [ 5],
       [10]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does casting the index from a scalar to a list do the trick?